# Some small parts of the mesh are unpaintable in texture paint

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am trying to paint this leg blue, but some parts can not be painted(the white stripes on the blue leg). How do I solve this? I used smart uv project to unwrap the mesh.

[image: The part of the mesh that I want to paint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to increase the *Bleed* value in the *Tools* panel > *Options* > *Project Paint*. It gives your brush a bit margin around the borders of your UV islands.

[image]